# Property "CFileValidator.0" is not defined yii

Tags: yii

What does this mean exactly? 
Here is my model rules, or does this error relate to something else?

```
array('product_gallery_2, product_gallery_3, product_gallery_4, product_gallery_5, product_gallery_6', 'safe'=>true, 'file', 'allowEmpty' => TRUE,'types'=>'jpg, jpeg, png, gif', 'maxSize' => 600000, 'on'=>'insert,update,create'),
array('product_image,product_gallery_1', 'file',  'safe'=>true,'types'=>'jpg, jpeg, png, gif', 'maxSize' => 600000, 'on'=>'insert,update,create'),
array('product_image,product_gallery_1, product_gallery_2, product_gallery_3, product_gallery_4, product_gallery_5, product_gallery_6', 'length', 'max'=>50,'message'=>'{attribute} name is too long.'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT :

[`safe`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFileValidator#safe-detail) (`CFileValidator` attribute, not validator) should be set **after** 'file' entry in your rules, e.g. :

```
array('product_gallery_2, product_gallery_3, product_gallery_4, product_gallery_5, product_gallery_6', 'file', 'safe'=>true, 'allowEmpty' => TRUE,'types'=>'jpg, jpeg, png, gif', 'maxSize' => 600000, 'on'=>'insert,update,create'),
array('product_image,product_gallery_1', 'file', 'safe'=>true, 'types'=>'jpg, jpeg, png, gif', 'maxSize' => 600000, 'on'=>'insert,update,create'),
```

Comment: I had that before then it said `Failed to set unsafe attribute "product_gallery_2" of "Product".`